# Set fields name before values with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

**Edited:**

I want to set fields name before values?

```
->setCellValue('A1','ID');  
->setCellValue('B1','Email');  
->setCellValue('C1','Phone');  
....
```

I have many fields

Codes:

```
$rowNumber = 1;
// Loop through the result set
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','ID')
                                  ->setCellValue('B1','Email')
                                      ..... etc               
                                  ->setCellValue('A'.$rowNumber,$row->id)
                                  ->setCellValue('B'.$rowNumber,$row->email);   
                                      ...... etc          
       $rowNumber++;
}
```

Is there another option?

Comment: PS. Set your headings in Row 1 outside of the while loop rather than repeating setting them for every single row of data

Comment: Please don't keep editing the original question when you have a new question: ask a new question... otherwise it's a lot harder for anybody else trying to get help with similar issues.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I'll consider your advice while editing :) promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you do this if you were outputting it to a simple HTML table? Outputting to Excel isn't much different.

```
$rowNumber = 1;
// Loop through the result set
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$rowNumber,$row['id'].' Mr '.$row['name']);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowNumber,$row['email']);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowNumber,$row['title']);
   $rowNumber++;
}
```

or even...

```
$rowNumber = 1;
// Loop through the result set
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$rowNumber,$row['id'].' Mr '.$row['name'])
                                 ->setCellValue('B'.$rowNumber,$row['email'])
                                 ->setCellValue('C'.$rowNumber,$row['title']);
   $rowNumber++;
}
```

**EDIT**

Another option, based on your edit of the question:

Modify your SQL query to do the concatenation and adding 'Mr' for you, so that the returned row contains only the actual values that you want to write in each cell of the Excel row, then use the fromArray() method to write each row to the worksheet.

Comment: thanks. Should I use `  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','ID')
` before the while?

Comment: Yes, set your heading row before the while loop... otherwise, you're just duplicating setting every heading cell

Comment: Wow that's so easy :) It's like I work with HTML output :) Thanks again

Comment: is there an online docs (manual) for PHPexcel? It will be very useful

Comment: There is currently no online docs for PHPExcel.... at the moment, it's just all bundled in the /Documentation folder with the download. It's on my "to do" list for the next few months

Answer (score 0):

use this code to use auto header print excel head from data base

```
    $headerArr=array("id","Email","Phone");
    $newsheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
    $colH = 'A';
    $rowNumberH=1;
    foreach ($headerArr as $h) {
        $newsheet->setCellValue($colH . $rowNumberH, $h);
        $colH++;
    }
```